# Orika - Map object to null if all fields of object are null

Tags: java, mapping, field, orika

I got 2 classes `A` and `B` which both got a company. The company of `A` has got a little more information than the company of `B` (`Company` has an `id` while `CNCompany` doesn´t). I want to map all fields using orika. If all fields an object are null, I want the object to be null!

I tried to express this with an unit test. What has to be done to get this running?

```
public class A {

    private Company company;

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

}

public class B {

    private CNCompany company;

    public CNCompany getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(CNCompany company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

}

public class Company {

    private Id id;
    private AccountId accountId;

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AccountId getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(AccountId accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

}

public class CNCompany {

    private AccountId accountId

    public AccountId getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(AccountId accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

}

public class MyMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {
    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
        factory.classMap(A.class, B.class) //
                .mapNulls(false).mapNullsInReverse(false) //
                .byDefault() //
                .register();
    }
}

@Test
public void testMap() throws Exception {
    A a = new A();

    Company company = new Company();
    Id id = new Id();
    id.setValue("1");
    company.setId(id);
    a.setCompany(company);

    MyMapper myMapper = new MyMapper();
    B outcome = myMapper.map(a, B.class);

    assertThat(outcome.getCompany(), is(nullValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want `getCompany` to return `null` if the `Company` object contains only null values.

In Orika you can control *conversion* with a [custom converter](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/converters.html).  For your example that might look something like:

```
public class CompanyConverter extends CustomConverter<Company, CNCompany> {
    public CNCompany convert(Company source, Type<? extends CNCompany> destinationType) {
        if (isNothingButNulls(source)) {
            return null;
        }
        final CNCompany newCompany = new CNCompany();
        // do your thing
        return newCompany;
    }
}
```

I've never written a `CustomConverter` that can return `null` so I'm not 100% sure this will work but it should.  Note that the converter will still need to be registered.  The documentation I linked shows how to register depending on what level you want the converter at.

Comment: The problem is the method isNothingButNulls(source). I need to traverse all childs (and child of childs and so on) and check whether they are null.

Comment: Off the top of my head I think you could use reflections to iterate over children and check for null.  I kind of figured that was the easy part but now that I think about it more that is going to be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Just imagine you want to do this for different kind of objects / certain objects in other objects (cascade)...